# SMS Forwarding with Twilio

Tags: php, twilio

I've been trying to build an app that forwards an sms to a URL
with twilio, i.e, a user sends an sms to a twilio number, the sms gets forwarded to a specified url, can't seems to find the resource on that, any experienced person in that area
to give a hint, plus what is the format of the sms forwarded to the url.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I was able to find what I was looking for. Phew!

`$_REQUEST['Body']` retrieves the body of the sms message and I can do whatever I like with that.

Twilio rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest working through the SMS and MMS Messages Quickstart.  It will walk you through the PHP needed to receive a text message:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for dropping by.I was able to specify a url to receive incoming message,now,the docs say I should paste this code in my script:                                                             <?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response><Message>Hello, Mobile Monkey</Message>
</Response>                                                         I did that,I didn't see anything happen,I'll like to know the format of the forwared message, i.e url query string parameters, something similar to bit.ly/Igl151

Comment: Let's say I want to save the forwarded message and the source phone number to my database, how do I retrieve these info from the forwarded message, since query string parameters are not specified.